# Redirect react router parent JSX route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, I'd like to redirect a parent route to a child route.  Something like the following...

```
<Redirect path='legal' to='terms-and-conditions'>
  <Redirect path='tac' to='terms-and-conditions' />
  <Route path='terms-and-conditions' component={TermsAndConditions} />
</Redirect>
```

However, I get the error, `<Redirect> should not have a "children" prop`.  I understand why, but is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to achieve a redirect to a child, is to use `IndexRedirect` like so:

```
<Route path='legal'>
  <IndexRedirect to='terms-and-conditions' />

  <Redirect from='tac' to='terms-and-conditions' />
  <Route path='terms-and-conditions' component={TermsAndConditions} />
</Route>
```

[IndexRedirect documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects)

However, the issue that I'm currently having is that the redirect doesn't actually appear to be working in my case.  The `/legal` route generates a blank page in my case.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve redirection you should go in this format.

```
<Route component={App}>
  <Route path="terms-and-conditions" component={TermsAndConditions} />
  <Redirect from="tac" to="terms-and-conditions" />
</Route>
```

Comment: That's fine for a basic redirect, but that's not the solution to this issue.  It needs to redirect to a child.  I'm trying to redirect `/legal` to `/legal/terms-and-conditions`